# Colouring the surface of a tetrahedra in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to colour the faces of the tetrahedra determined by the edges shown here in green:

[image]

The plot is generated using this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection


%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    
x,y,z = nCompoundTetra(bloch_vectors,nTetrahedron).getEdges()

x,y,z = list(x)[0],list(y)[0],list(z)[0]
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "black", s = 3.5)
ax.plot(x,y,z, color="g",  linewidth= 1)    

ax.set_xlim([-1.1, 1.1])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
ax.set_zlim([-1.1, 1.1])

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

xs = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
ys = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
zs = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_wireframe(xs, ys, zs, color="grey", alpha=0.15)
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([5, 5, 7, 7]))

ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

`nCompoundTetra(bloch_vectors,nTetrahedron).getEdges()` is a method I'm implementing to generate more tetrahedron

Comment: So, you left out the most important function from your post?  Based on how `nCompoundTetra(bloch_vectors,nTetrahedron).getEdges()` works, you could also create a `nCompoundTetra(bloch_vectors,nTetrahedron).getFaces()`.  Each face would be 3 xy coordinates (depending on how they are plotted, it could be 4 coordinates with the first coordinate repeated at the end).  Note that matplotlib has rather limited 3D capabilities.  You might want to use a library such as Mayavi for full 3D stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The function has nothing to do with the plotting. I'll check Mayavi.

Comment: Well, for plotting the faces, you need the geometry of the faces. If you only give the edges, it's hard for the code to know which edges go together to form a polygon. If your polyhedron is convex, you could create the polygons from the convex hull of all the vertices.